# React Navigation switching background colors and styling StackNavigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation, navigator

I'm fairly new to React Native, but I have a simple working app with three scenes. I was previously using Navigator but it felt laggy and was excited to try out React Navigation (as in https://reactnavigation.org/). After implementing React Navigation, my background color switched from white to grey, and what was grey to white. This is a strange and shouldn't be related. However I didn't change my styles. I only implemented the new navigation and the colors changed. When I revert back to Navigator my colors return. I'm using StackNavigator. Has anyone else encountered this strange phenomenon?

Or maybe a better question is : how do I style my header and background color in React Navigation's StackNavigator?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

To style the header in React Navigation use a header object inside the navigationOptions object:

```
static navigationOptions = {  
  header: {
    titleStyle: {
     /* this only styles the title/text (font, color etc.)  */
    },
    style: {
     /* this will style the header, but does NOT change the text */
    },
    tintColor: {
      /* this will color your back and forward arrows or left and right icons */
    }
  }
}
```

For styling the `backgroundColor`, you just need to set the `backgroundColor` in your app otherwise you'll get the default color.

***UPDATE!! As of May 2017 beta9 the navigationOptions are now flat***

You can [read about the breaking change here](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/releases/tag/v1.0.0-beta.9)

You need to remove the object keys from the header object. Also, notice they have been renamed.

```
static navigationOptions = {
   title: 'some string title',
   headerTitleStyle: {
      /*  */
   },
   headerStyle: {
      /*  */
   },
   headerTintColor: {
      /*  */
   },
}
```

Answer (score 22):

Here is an example of what I am using to change the card background color and Header background and font color.

```js
/*
1. Change React Navigation background color.
- change the style backgroundColor property in the StackNavigator component
- also add a cardStyle object to the Visual options config specifying a background color
*/

//your new background color
let myNewBackgroundColor = 'teal';

const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  SomeLoginScreen: {
    screen: SomeLoginScreen
  }
}, {
      headerMode: 'screen', 
      cardStyle: {backgroundColor: myNewBackgroundColor
   }
});

//add the new color to the style property
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return ( 
        <AppNavigator style = {{backgroundColor: myNewBackgroundColor}} ref={nav => {this.navigator = nav;}}/>
    );
  }
}

/*
2. Change React Navigation Header background color and text color.
- change the StackNavigator navigationOptions 
*/

/*
its not clear in the docs but the tintColor 
changes the color of the text title in the 
header while a new style object changes the 
background color.
*/


//your new text color
let myNewTextColor = 'forestgreen';

//your new header background color
let myNewHeaderBackgroundColor = 'pink';

const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  SomeLoginScreen: {
    screen: SomeLoginScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Register',
      header: {
        tintColor: myNewTextColor,
        style: {
          backgroundColor: myNewHeaderBackgroundColor
        }
      },
    }
  }
}, {
     headerMode: 'screen',
     cardStyle:{backgroundColor:'red'
   }
});
```

Comment: Probably the better answer because it applies to the whole stack.

Answer (score 6):

> Use below code to create custom navigation header

```
static navigationOptions = {
          title: 'Home',
          headerTintColor: '#ffffff',
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#2F95D6',
            borderBottomColor: '#ffffff',
            borderBottomWidth: 3,
          },
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontSize: 18,
          },
      };
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this code.

```
 static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'KindleJoy - Kids Learning Center',
        headerTintColor: '#ffffff',
        /*headerBackground: (
            <Image
                style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
                source={require('./imgs/yr_logo.png')}
            />
        ),*/
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#1d7110',
            borderBottomColor: 'black',
            borderBottomWidth: 0,
        },
        headerTitleStyle: {
            fontSize: 18,
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 4):

I think none of the above answers worked for me in `react-navigation 5` so, I made it mine own solution and share it with you

Just changed background of your `theme` in `react-navigation 5` and you are good to go.

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer, DefaultTheme } from '@react-navigation/native';

const MainNavigator = () => {
  const MyTheme = {
    ...DefaultTheme,
    colors: {
      ...DefaultTheme.colors,
      background: '#FFF',
    },
  };

  return (
    <NavigationContainer theme={MyTheme}>
      ...
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default MainNavigator;
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/themes/

Answer (score 0):

Ok nothing worked for me, so I managed to figure out my own solution

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation, screenProps }) => ({
        headerLeft: (
              <NavBackButton onPress={() => { navigation.goBack(); }} />
        ),headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: CLColors.MAIN_BLUE
        }, 
        headerTitle: <Text style={[CLStyles.H6MEDIUM_WHITE, {marginLeft:8}]}>Profile</Text>
        , footer: null,
     });
```

`headerTitle` will do the magic to place a custom `Text` element here.

`headerStyle` will do the magic to change the background color of your navbar.

`headerLeft` will help you to customize your back button.

Answer (score 0):

In stack navigator you can change it with contentStyle.backgroundColor like below syntax

```
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ contentStyle: {backgroundColor: '#f6f6f6f'}}}>
```

note: #f6f6f6f is colour code of red colour you can change it as per your requirement, below is extra code snippets in case

```
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar style='auto' />
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ contentStyle: {backgroundColor: '#f6f6f6f'}}}>
          <Stack.Screen name="List Page" component={ListPage} />
          <Stack.Screen name="List Page 2" component={ListPage} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </>
  );
}
```