# How to change React Native Navigation overflow menu color / icon?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Is there a way to change the overflow menu color / icon in React Native Navigation?

The menu appears automatically when righButton has the property `showAsAction: 'never'`. By default it's black and is hard to see when the background is dark.

[image]

Comment: check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42261011/react-navigation-switching-background-colors-and-styling-stacknavigator

Comment: Your answer is related to React Navigation, not React Native Navigation. These are two different libraries.

Comment: sorry, you're right. can you post the code of the current topbar configuration?

Comment: ```
  {
      topBar: {
        title: {
          text: 'Blah',
        },
        backButton: {
          color: Colors.MenuAction,
        },
        rightButtons: [{
          id,
          text,
          icon: Images.clearBlack,
          color: Colors.menu,
          showAsAction: 'never',
        }],
      },
    };
```

Comment: ok, you can either change the color by default in 'Colors.menu' or set the color of the right button directly in topBar with the rightButtonColor option (see the option here: wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/api/options-stack/#rightbuttoncolor)

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot! :)